# 3d Random sampling

Tags: python, numpy, points, random

I have a set of points xyz8,

I want to randomly get 10% of points.

Then I want to randomly get 10% of the remaining 90%

Then I want to randomly get 10% of the remaining 70%

etc until all points done

How can I go about doing this?

Any advice is hugely appreciated

Comment: Suppose you have 1000 elements, the first round you sample 100. In the second round, do you sample 100 from 900 or 90 from 900?

Comment: @CTZhu Oh, now I understand your comment on my question. Obviously I assumed OP meant 10% of the total each time, not of the remainder ... this avoids zeno's paradox, but who knows what the application is.

Comment: yes sorry 10% of the total , see comment below. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
import random

l = [1,2,3,4]
random.shuffle(l)
while len(l) > 0:
    choice = l[:len(l) / 10]
    l = l[len(l) / 10:]
```

Answer (score 1):

I interpret this as you want to split the points into 10 equal-sized segments.  You can simply do this by shuffling them and reshaping the list:

```
np.random.shuffle(points)
points.shape = (10,-1) + points.shape[1:]
```

Then you can access the first 10% as `points[0]`, the second as `points[1]`, etc.

This still works for a multidimensional array since shuffle will only shuffle along the first axis.

Comment: I am not sure this is correct. The result of this implementation would mean the probability of being sampled are the same in each of the 10 10% segments. But in the original question, the first set has p=0.1, the second has p=(1-0.1)*0.1=0.09 and so on. The probability is not equal across all 10 segments.

Comment: No, each particle has equal chance of being in each division, regardless of the order of the sampling. Otherwise the probability does not add to 1.

Comment: I have 50 XYZC. I need A random 10% of those numbers eg 5 , I perform a calculation on the C for these 5 numbers , then i need another different 5 numbers, perform a calculation on there C . Then i need another different 5 numbers,  perform a calculation on there C. And do this until I have no numbers left. Everytime I do a calculation on the C i need it to change on the total 50XYZC

Comment: My application has to do with a point cloud simplification method im working on